# HashMap <Foo,Fn(Foo)> size for values of type `(dyn Fn(Foo) + 'static)` cannot be known

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to create a sort-of observer pattern in rust and I am getting a compile error that is basically telling me (I think) it doesn't know the size of a function param at runtime. I didn't realize the size of a function pointer was unknown at runtime. More importantly, I don't have a clue how to tell it the size

```sh
christianb@christianb-mac debug % cargo build
   Compiling pyrsia-blockchain v0.1.0 (/Users/christianb/dev/jfrog/rusty-brown)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Fn(Foo) -> Result<(), (dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:45:16
    |
45  |     observers: HashMap<&'a Foo, OnFooDone>,
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Fn(Foo) -> Result<(), (dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `HashMap`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:45:16
    |
45  |     observers: HashMap<&'a Foo, OnFooDone>,
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Result`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:49:54
    |
49  |     pub fn submit_foo(&mut self, foo: &Foo, on_done: OnFooDone) -> &Self {
    |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Result`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `pyrsia-blockchain` due to 3 previous errors
```

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let mut holder = Holder {
        observers: HashMap::new()
    };
    let foo0 = Foo {
        id: 0,
        stuff: **"hello",
    };
    let foo1 = Foo {
        id: 1,
        stuff: **"world",
    };
    let mut foo2 = Foo {
        id: 2,
        stuff: **"bob",
    };
    let mut magic_num = 5;
    let mut closure = |foo| {
        println!("Slow");
        magic_num += foo.id;
        foo.id
    };

    holder.submit_foo(&foo0, |f| {
        println!("received foo {}", f.id)?
    });
    holder.submit_foo(&foo1, |f| {
        println!("received foo2 {}", f.id)?
    });
    holder.submit_foo(&foo2, closure);

    holder.notify_all();
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Foo {
    id: u64,
    stuff: str,
}
type OnFooDone = dyn Fn(Foo) -> Result<(),dyn Error>;
pub struct Holder<'a> {
    observers: HashMap<&'a Foo, OnFooDone>,
}

impl Holder<'_> {
    pub fn submit_foo(&mut self, foo: &Foo, on_done: OnFooDone) -> &Self {
        self.observers.insert(foo, on_done);
        self
    }
    pub fn notify_all(self) -> Self {
        self.observers.iter().for_each(|k, f| f(k));
        self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```rust
type OnFooDone = dyn Fn(Foo) -> Result<(),dyn Error>;
```

This is a so-called [*unsized*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html?highlight=unsized#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait) type because its size is not known at compile time. It's not a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html?highlight=function%20pointer#function-pointers).

Let's start with the type itself. Imagine if you have just a regular function, but also a *closure*. It's pretty obvious now, that the closure is not the same size as the function pointer, but both implement `Fn`.

The same issue is present with the `Result`. What if the function returns several different types that implement `dyn Error` ?

The solution is to either use references or box the dynamically sized types:

- You can return a boxed error, such as `Box<dyn Error>>` instead of just `dyn Error`
- You can either box the `Fn`, just like we did with error above, or store a reference: `HashMap<&'a Foo, &'a OnFooDone>`

Thus we get:

```rust
type OnFooDone = dyn Fn(Foo) -> Result<(),Box<dyn Error>>;

pub struct Holder<'a> {
    observers: HashMap<&'a Foo, &'a OnFooDone>,
    // or with a boxed triat
    observers: HashMap<&'a Foo, Box<OnFooDone>>,
}
```

##### Resources:

- [Returning closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html?highlight=function%20pointer#returning-closures)